# Invalid helo name Jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, email, jhipster

I have set the file application-prod.yml with mail account but it is not working with mail server , it returns error 550 invalid helo name. i want to know where i can set host correctly.
thanks

```
mail:
        host: mail.xxxx.cloud
        port: 587
        username: register@xxxx.cloud
        password: xxxxxxxxxx
        protocol: smtp
        tls: true
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: mail.xxxx.cloud

...
...
...

    mail:
        from: register@xxxx.cloud
        base-url: https://host.xxxx.cloud/
```

Comment: Not really a JHipster question. It's rather a spring-boot question and depends on your mail provider. As you don't give any detail about this mail provider, it will be difficult for people to help you. Your question should also describe what you have attempted to debug the issue. Have you contacted the support of your mail provider?

Comment: i used the same credential on outlook client and it works perfect. the problem is on jhipster/java config need to set something...

Comment: Well, as we don't know anything about your Outlook configuration, it's impossible to say what you misconfigured in your spring boot properties. Have you read the JHipster tips about mail configuration? https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/011_tip_configuring_email_in_jhipster.html It shows how to configure spring boot for common mail providers

Comment: yes, i have composed my application-prod.yml following official documentation. .I am sure the email credentials are correct but i reiceve error 550 invalid helo name from server. mail provider reply to ticket is my problem because server is working well with webmail and other email clients.i want only help to understand the problem. i don't think it is jhipster problem, i think is only just a configuration issue.there is some logs to find other info? thanks

Comment: Try to add `debug: true` under `properties.mail.smtp:`. If it does not help; you could try to write a simpler program that does not depend on spring boot, it'll be easier to debug https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-debug-application-that-uses-javamail-apis/